# Interface management in Go

Tags: go, inheritance, polymorphism

I know this has been asked in various forms many times before but I just can't seem to implement what I'm learning in the way that I need. Any help is appreciated.

I have a series of exchanges which all implement roughly the same APIs. For example, each of them have a `GetBalance` endpoint. However, some have one or two unique things which need to be accessed within the functions. For example, `exchange1` needs to use a `client` when calling it's balance API, while `exchange2` requires both the `client` variable as well as a `clientFutures` variable. This is an important note for later.

My background is normal OOP. Obviously Go is different in many ways, hence I'm getting tripped up here.

My current implementation and thinking is as follows:

In `exchanges` module

```
type Balance struct {
    asset       string
    available   float64
    unavailable float64
    total       float64
}

type Api interface {
    GetBalances() []Balance
}
```

In `Binance` module

```
type BinanceApi struct {
    key           string
    secret        string
    client        *binance.Client
    clientFutures *futures.Client
    Api           exchanges.Api
}

func (v *BinanceApi) GetBalance() []exchanges.Balance {
    // Requires v.client and v.clientFutures
    return []exchanges.Balance{}
}
```

In `Kraken` module

```
type KrakenApi struct {
    key           string
    secret        string
    client        *binance.Client
    Api           exchanges.Api
}

func (v *KrakenApi) GetBalance() []exchanges.Balance {
    // Requires v.client
    return []exchanges.Balance{}
}
```

In `main.go`

```
var exchange *Api
```

Now my thought was I should be able to call something like `exchange.GetBalance()` and it would use the `GetBalance` function from above. I would also need some kind of casting? I'm quite lost here. The `exchange` could either be Binance or Kraken--that gets decided at runtime. Some other code basically calls a `GetExchange` function which returns an instance of the required API object (already casted in either BinanceApi/KrakenApi)

I'm aware inheritance and polymorphism don't work like other languages, hence my utter confusion. I'm struggling to know what needs to go where here. Go seems to require loads of annoying code necessary for what other languages do on the fly

Comment: `var exchange *Api` -- Bad. `var exchange Api` -- Good. Pointers to interfaces are pointless (pun intended).

Comment: Ah - good to know. And yeah now that you mention it, it makes sense. Thanks :)
I'll update my question.

Comment: What I had in mind was the top-level declaration in `main`. The `Api exchanges.Api` fields seem unnecessary, unless you want one exchange to be able to communicate with another exchange through the interface. Other than that, and apart from the use of unexported identifiers, the little bit of shared setup seems fine to me. Have you encountered any concrete problems with the design?

Comment: "Pointers to interfaces are pointless" -- Not literally true. There are (very very) rare cases to use a pointer to an interface. But as a general rule, yes, avoid pointers to interfaces. (When you need one, you'll know it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `*exchanges.Api` is quite weird. You're wanting something that implements a given interface. What the underlying type is (whether it's a pointer or a value receiver) is not important, so use `exchanges.Api` instead.

There is another issue, though. In golang, interfaces are implicit (sometimes referred to as duck-type interfaces). Generally speaking, this means that the interface is not declared in the package that implements it, but rather in the package that depends on a given interface. Some say that you should be liberal in terms of what values you return, but restrictive in terms of what arguments you accept. What this boils down to in your case, is that you'd have something like an `api` package, that looks somewhat like this:

```
package api

func NewKraken(args ...any) *KrakenExchange {
   // ...
}

func NewBinance(args ...any) *BinanceExchange {
}
```

then in your other packages, you'd have something like this:

```
package kraken // or maybe this could be an exchange package

type API interface {
    GetBalances() []types.Balance
}

func NewClient(api API, otherArgs ...T) *KrakenClient {
}
```

So when someone looks at the code for this `Kraken` package, they can instantly tell what dependencies are required, and what types it works with. The added benefit is that, should binance or kraken need additional API calls that aren't shared, you can go in and change the specific dependencies/interfaces, without ending up with one massive, centralised interface that is being used all over the place, but each time you only end up using a subset of the interface.

Yet another benefit of this approach is when writing tests. There are tools like `gomock` and mockgen, which allow you to quickly generate mocks for unit tests simply by doing this:

```
package foo

//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -destination mocks/dep_mock.go -package mocks your/module/path/to/foo Dependency
type Dependency interface {
    // methods here
}
```

Then run `go generate` and it'll create a mock object in `your/module/path/to/foo/mocks` that implements the desired interface. In your unit tests, import he `mocks` package, and you can do things like:

```
ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
dep := mocks.NewDependencyMock(ctrl)
defer ctrl.Finish()
dep.EXPECT().GetBalances().Times(1).Return(data)
k := kraken.NewClient(dep)
bal := k.Balances()
require.EqualValues(t, bal, data)
```

### TL;DR

The gist of it is:

- Interfaces are interfaces, don't use pointers to interfaces
- Declare interfaces in the package that depends on them (ie the user), not the implementation (provider) side.
- Only declare methods in an interface if you are genuinely using them in a given package. Using a central, overarching interface makes this harder to do.
- Having the dependency interface declared along side the user makes for self-documenting code
- Unit testing and mocking/stubbing is a lot easier to do, and to automate this way

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I'll try implement that. Can you show the usage though for, for example, `GetBalances()` on one of the exchanges?